# Adding numbers in TextBox

Tags: c#, function, textbox, null

I have this code that it works only if all the textBox contains values.. But if a textbox is empty i get an error..

```
Int32 Total = Int32.Parse((txtChild1.Text))
            + Int32.Parse(txtChild2.Text)
            + Int32.Parse(txtChild3.Text)
            + Int32.Parse(txtWife1.Text)
            + Int32.Parse(txtWife2.Text)
            + Int32.Parse(txtWife3.Text);
```

I know that it must be a function like IsNull but for the integer values.. 
Does anyone know what it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Int32.TryParse`:

```
Int32 int1 = 0;
Int32.TryParse(txtChild1.Text, out int1);
//.... more int declarations
Int32 total = int1 + int2 + int3; //etc. etc.
```

`TryParse` will try to parse the text and if it fails, it will set the variable to 0.

You can also inline some of the logic (although this makes the code very long and messy):

```
Int32 Total = (txtChild1.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : Int32.TryParse(txtChild1.Text)) + (txtChild2.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : Int32.TryParse(txtChild2.Text)); //etc. etc.
```

`Int32.TryParse` reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Shorthand if reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No problem, Brad beat me to it and his answer is better anyway =]

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
Int32 val;
if (Int32.TryParse(txtChild1.Text, out val)){
  // val is a valid integer.
}
```

Which you call on every `.Text` property, then add them together. You can also make an extension to make it easier (if you chose):

```
public static class NumericParsingExtender
{
    public static Int32 ToInt32(this String input, Int32 defaultValue = 0)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return defaultValue;
      Int32 val;
      return Int32.TryParse(input, out val) ? val : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Then, in practice:

```
Int32 total = txtChild1.Text.ToInt32() + txtChild2.Text.ToInt32()
            + txtChild3.Text.ToInt32() + /* ... */;
```

And, of course, [an example](http://ideone.com/vEhc5L)

Answer (score 2):

you should check if the `TextBox` is not empty before parsing it or you can use `TryParse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: I think what you are referring to is `TryParse`

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse an empty string "". Check if the box contains anything before parsing.

```
Textbox.text != ""
```

Other answers are quicker to use tryparse is the best in fact, as it does the same with less lines of code!

Comment: An empty string isn't the same as `null`

Answer (score 1):

`Int32` is a *value type*. It can't be `null`. Or course there is a `nullable types` but hey..

Try with [`Int32.Tryparse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method.

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

```
Int32.TryParse(txtChild1.Text, out val)
```

returns `boolean` `true` if s was converted successfully; otherwise, `false`.